# Laravel: 2 text fields into 1 database record

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a form to edit users with a company.
I got a `disabled field` with the company (which the user is added to) and a field with the `account id`.

Now I want that the `tag` + `id` is added to the same column `account_id`

So for example:

John works for Invis.

[image]

`INV-012345` will be uploaded to the database column `account_id`

As for now it will only upload `012345` to the database.

Now the problem is that I have no clue how both these fields can be uploaded to the `account_id` column.

*HTML/Blade*

```
<div class="form-group  {{ $errors->has('account_id') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    {!! Form::label('account_id', trans('common.account_id'), ['class' => 'form-label col-sm-3 control-label text-capitalize']) !!}
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        {!! Form::text('account_id', $user->company->abbreviation, ['class' => 'form-control col-sm-3', 'id' => 'disabledInput', 'disabled']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        {!! Form::text('account_id', null, ['class' => 'form-control  col-sm-9', 'placeholder' => trans('common.account_id') ])  !!}
        {!! $errors->first('account_id', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

*Controller*

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
private $user;

public  function  __construct(User $user,CompaniesController $companies, UserTypeController $userType)
{
    $cid = Auth::user()->company_id;

    if(Auth::user()->usertype_id == 7)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
    else
    {
        $array_company_ids = $companies->getCompany_ids($cid);
        $this->user = $user->whereIn('company_id', $array_company_ids);
    }

}

public function index()
{
    $users = $this->user->with('company', 'usertype')->get();

    return view('user.index', compact('users'));
}

public function show()
{
    //
}

public function create(CompaniesController $companies,  UserTypeController $userType)
{
    $companies = $companies->getCompanies(Auth::user()->company_id);
    $usertypes = $userType->getUsertypes();

    return view('user.create', ['usertypes' => $usertypes,'companies' => $companies]);
}

public function store(CreateUserRequest $request, User $user)
{
    $user->fill($request->all());
    $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
    $user->save();
    return redirect()->route('user.index');
}

public function edit($user_id, CompaniesController $companies,  UserTypeController $userType)
{
    $user = $this->user->with('company')->findOrFail($user_id);
    $companies = $companies->getCompaniesName(Auth::user()->company_id);
    $usertypes = $userType->getUsertypes();

    return view('user.edit', ['user' => $user, 'usertypes' => $usertypes, 'companies' => $companies]);
}

public function update($id, CreateUserRequest $request)
{
    $user = $this->user->find($id);

    $password = $request->input('password');

    if($password)
    {
        $user->fill($request->input())->save();
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));

        $user->save();
    }
    else
    {
        $user->fill($request->only('account_id', 'email',  'firstname',
            'lastname', 'middlename', 'usertype_id', 'active',
            'company_id','title','btw_nr','kvk_nr','bic','iban',
            'birthday','mobile','telephone','country','city','postal_code',
            'house_nr','street'));

        $user->save();
    }

    if ($request->input('usertype_id') <= Auth::user()->usertype_id)
    {
        $user->usertype_id = $request->input('usertype_id');

        $user->save();
    }

    $user->update();

    return redirect()->route('user.index');
}


public function destroy($user)
{
    $user->delete();
    return redirect('user');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is if I understand what you are trying to do.

You need to break down what you are saving and concatenate the two parts of data.

Firstly in your blade have them as separate form fields e.g.

```
{!! Form::text('account_id') !!}
{!! Form::text('tag') !!}
```

Use this when running a function to update a user

```
$user = $this->user->find($id);

$user->account_id = $request['tag']."-".$request['account_id'];

//Insert all other fields here e.g.
$user->email = $request['email'];

//To save the data use
$user->save();
```

Comment: This is exactly what you have right now but it doesn't seem to send the tag with the account_id part.. For this particular example it will only send `-012345` if I dd($user). Without the dd I will get an `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'abbreviation' in 'field list' (SQL: update `users` set `account_id` = t1233123123123, `updated_at` = 2015-06-02 09:30:12, `abbreviation` = where `id` = 9)`

Comment: Okay it works now. Only problem is now that it will give `INV` `INV-12345` since it will get the account_id, so I need to split the first 4 characters somehow

Comment: Okay, could you paste your code for the whole process please?